# String splitting regex with patterns ignored

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a source string that I want to split the `data` out:

```
String source = "data|junk,data|junk|junk,data,data|junk";
String[] result = source.split(",");
```

The above gives `data|junk, data|junk|junk, data, data|junk`. To further get the data out, I did this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = result[i].split("\\|")[0];
}
```

Which gives what I wanted `data, data, data, data`. I want to see if it is possible to do it in one split with the right regex:

```
String[] result = source.split("\\|.*?,");
```

The above gives `data, data, data,data|junk`, in which the last two data are not split. Could you please help with the correct regex to get the result I wanted?

Example string: "Ann|xcjiajeaw,Bob|aijife|vdsjisdjfe,Clara,David|rijfidjf"

Expected result: "Ann, Bob, Clara, David"

Comment: if `source = "data|junk, junk|junk"` , your result will be String[0] = "data" and String[1] = null or String[1] = "junk" ?

Comment: There is no source like this. All the parts before the first '|' are the data I want. Or of there is no multi-part with '|', the whole part between ',' is the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the string,

> Ann|xcjiajeaw,Bob|aijife|vdsjisdjfe,Clara,David|rijfidjf

`\\|.*?,` - this will match `|anynoncommastring,`
but this doesn't match the final `|rijfidjf` since that does not end in comma. So to match that, use `(,|$)` instead of just `,`, making the regex `\\|.*?(,|$)`

But the above does not match a single isolated comma, so alternating `,` with `\\|.*?(,|$)`, makes the final regex `(\\|.*?(,|$)|,)`.

The pattern `(\\|.*?(,|$)|,)` works,

```
String source = "Ann|xcjiajeaw,Bob|aijife|vdsjisdjfe,Clara,David|rijfidjf";
String[] result = source.split("(\\|.*?(,|$)|,)");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(result[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
Ann
Bob
Clara
David
```

Comment: Thanks. I like yours being the shortest. If you can add some explanations so I know how to compose or come up with this regex then I will pick yours as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your regular expression to account for the "junk", then keep matching while it matches data:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Ann|xcjiajeaw,Bob|aijife|vdsjisdjfe,Clara,David|rijfidjf";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(\\|\\w+)*,?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

The regular expression looks for word characters (letters, digits, and underscores) and captures that. It then looks for a pipe symbol (escaped so that that it does not have a special meaning in the regular expression) with again word characters. This pipe plus word characters can happen any number (zero to many) of times. After that could be a comma, optionally.

This prints

> Ann
>
> Bob
>
> Clara
>
> David

It also captures the "junk", and you could access that with `m.group(2)` in the loop. If you don't want to capture that, insert a `?:` into the regular expression:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(?:\\|\\w+)*,?");
```

Comment: Ah ok, using capture group will work. But I can't use it directly as the regex for split. Since I am after a split regex, I will pick the other as the answer. But surely great info here for others who wants to use capture groups. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution:

```
String source = "one|junk,two|junk|junk,three,four|junk|junk";
String[] result = source.split("([|](?:(.*?,(?=[^,]+[|,]|$))|.*$))|,");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

[one, two, three, four]
```

Comment: Thanks! This also works. But @boobalan 's answer is shorter, I think I will pick his.

Comment: @user1589188 Yes his answer is very clever.  Sadly, this is the best I could do.